# JSON Object - JavaScript, C#, MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have this `for` that fills an array, where the `cont` came from View

```js
function GenerateJSON(cont) {
        var songs= [];

        for (var i = 0; i <= cont; i++) {
            songs[i] = {
                id: i,
                genre: $(".genre" + i).val(),
                song: $(".song" + i).val()
           }
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "Generate",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: { songs: JSON.stringify(songs) },
            success: function (data) {
            }
        })
    }
```

On Controller, i got only one block music

example:

```
songs= [{"id":0,"genre":"","song":"","id":1,"genre":"","song":"","id":2,"genre":"","song":""}]
```

I want this:

```
songs=[{"id":0,"genre":"","song":""},{"id":1,"genre":"","song":""},{id":2,"genre":"","song":""}]
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult Generate(string[] songs)
    {}
```

Comment: Sorry, Leooso. Questions to this site need to be posted in English.

Comment: ooooh, sorry, i'll translate

Comment: why not use a view model with that structure instead of using string and then later parsing ?

Comment: you can't have the same variable holding 3 different values... the better approach you can get is to have a `songs` array with objects inside, something like: `songs = [{"id":0...}, {"id":1...}, ...]`

Comment: @CalvinNunes, yes, that is what i like: songs = [{"id":0...}, {"id":1...},...], sorry. But i cant do it.. i'll edit

Comment: you know that in `GenerateJSON()` is missing a `}` right after `song: $(".song" + i).val()`  right?  Or is it to be an ajax Call to every `for` loop?

Comment: oh, yes, its happend only to paste here

Comment: sorry, careless mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a string array as the parameter does not make sense to me. Now you have to make client side code to build some sophisticated string  and in server side you have to parse it to get each item's property values.

IMHO, The clean approach is to use a view model and take advantage of MVC model binding. Start by creating a view model to represent your data.

```
public class SongVm
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Genre { set; get; }
    public string Song { set; get; }
}
```

Now use this as the parameter of your action method. Since you want to send a collection of your objects, use `List<SongVm>` as your parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Gerar(List<SongVm> songs)
{
    // Simply returning the data with a message property as well
    return Json(new { messge ="success", data = songs });
}
```

Now from the client side code, send the JSON string version of your array, while specifying `application/json` as the value of `contentType` property of the option we are passing to the `$.ajax` method.

```
var songs = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= cont; i++) {
    songs[i] = {
        id: i,
        genre : "test genre" + i,
        song : "test song" + i
    };
}

$.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Gerar",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(songs),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            console.log(c);
        }
 })
```

Now `$.ajax` will add the request header `Content-Type` to the call with the value `application/json`. As part of model binding, the default model binder will read this request header value and then decide to read the data from the request body(Request payload)

I would also recommend leveraging the Url helper methods like `Url.Action` to generate the correct relative path to the action method.

Comment: i'll try, im new with ajax and how to pass data between view and controller

Comment: i get an error, a: [object Object] - b: error - c: Not Found

Comment: Looks like your code is getting into the `error` handler. Do you have it written as `error: function (a, b, c)` ?

Comment: i got it. Thank you so much, another careless mistake, i put /../Generate (english) but i needed /../Gerar (my language)

Comment: Good answer with nice examples of the Model, the Controller and the View!